# Method Cannot be Applied to Given Types Java

Tags: java

I have an app that, when a number is entered, will provide the day of week. I have a date class that uses a Switch and Case where the number is assigned to a string. However, when I try to execute the code there is an issue with it. I can't figure out how to add it so a JOptionPane will get the user input and print out the answer. 
This is my code that sets the values:

```
public static int dayToNumber(String strDay) {

    int dayNum;

    switch (strDay.toLowerCase()) {
        case "monday":
            dayNum = 2;
            break;
        case "tuesday":
            dayNum = 3;
            break;
        case "wednesday":
            dayNum = 4;
            break;
        case "thursday":
            dayNum = 5;
            break;
        case "friday":
            dayNum = 6;
            break;
        case "staurday":
            dayNum = 7;
            break;    
        case "sunday":
            dayNum = 1;
            break;        
        default:
            dayNum = -1;
            break;
    }
    return dayNum;   
}
```

>
This is the code where I execute the main code (where I need the help):

```
String strDay;
int day;
int dayNum; 

strDay = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter in a day number");

day = Integer.parseInt(strDay);
Date anotherDate = new Date();
anotherDate.setDay(day);

dayNum = anotherDate.dayToNumber(); // Error


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Day number:" + dayNum);
```

I've attached an image of what the error says
[image]

Comment: `dayToNumber(String strDay)` expects a String as argument, right? Are you passing a String as argument when you execute `anotherDate.dayToNumber()`?

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing the point but isn't your code wrong considering what you prompt the user for and what your method does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't put the `strDay` value. According to the method signature `public static int dayToNumber(String strDay)` you must put one.

Comment: It now works. However, when I enter in a string into the input dialog box, it crashes and throws an exception. What do I do now?

Comment: Well, what input do you want from a user? A day number or day of week? You expect a day number but you compare it with a day of week in your switch statement. If you want a day of week do not parse it as 'int' because you will get the exception.

Comment: this is why you do not answer duplicates

Comment: I had the code wrong with the question. I'm asking for the day of week from the user (Monday, Tuesday, etc.) and giving back the number (1, 2, 3).